# Two proof problems about orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem 1**
$\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathcal{S}$ iff $\mathcal{S}^\perp \subseteq \mathcal{R}^\perp$

**Problem 2**
$(\mathcal{R} \cap \mathcal{S})^\perp = \mathcal{R}^\perp+\mathcal{S}^\perp$

**What I Have Done**

These two problems seem to be pretty fundamental but I failed to find materials that could help me.

I have proved something similar to the second problem, which is $(\mathcal{R} + \mathcal{S})^\perp = \mathcal{R}^\perp \cap \mathcal{S}^\perp$. But I could not do similar things that I did when I proved this similar problem.

What is more, could you recommend a comprehensive book on matrix analysis (hopefully the materials are detailed and contain some working examples). The textbook I use now seems to be too concise and sometimes very difficult to understand the topics covered.

Thank you in advance, I do appreciate your help.

Comment: the orthogonality is made by a inner product?

Comment: there were few mistakes in my demonstration, So I deleted it until I can fix