# Proof of two properties of orthogonal complements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Assume that $X_1\subseteq V$ and $X_2 \subseteq V$

How can we prove that:

1) If $X_1 \subseteq X_2$ then $X_2^\perp\subseteq X_1 ^\perp$

2)  a) $(X_1+X_2)^\perp=X_1^\perp\cap X_2^\perp$ and  b) $(X_1\cap X_2)^\perp=X_1^\perp+X_2^\perp$

I found these 2 posts which are related to at least one of these problems, I could not comprehend the proof in the first post and the second post was unanswered. I was also hinted that I should use the definition of the orthogonal supplement to prove at least the first one but I couldn't do it despite my efforts.

[orthogonal complement of a sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744511/orthogonal-complement-of-a-sum)

[Two proof problems about orthogonal complement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483482/two-proof-problems-about-orthogonal-complement)

Edit: This is the proof I came up for (2a) after the help I got from the answers:

$\begin
{align}X_1^\perp\cap X_2^\perp=\{y:\langle y,x\rangle=0\ \ \forall x_1\in X_1,\ \ \forall x_2\in X_2\}=\{y\in V:\langle x_1,y\rangle=0\ \ \& \ \ \langle x_2,y\rangle=0\ \ \forall x_1\in X_1,\ \ \forall x_2\in X_2\}=\{y\in V:\langle x_1,y\rangle + \langle x_2,y\rangle=0 \ \ \forall x_1\in X_1, \ \ \forall x_2\in X_2 \}=(X_1+X_2)^\perp
\end{align}$

Is this correct?

As for (2b), I think it's $X_1^\perp + X_2^\perp = \{y_1 + y_2 : y_1 \in X_1^\perp \text{ and }y_2 \in X_2^\perp\}\\$  we got to work with, but its definition seems to differ a bit compared to the other ones on the list. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to proceed with it to reach the desired result, which would be:

$(X_1 \cap X_2)^\perp = \{y : \langle y,x \rangle = 0 \text{ for all } x \in X_1 \cap X_2\}$

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? Do you understand the definition of the orthogonal complement?

Comment: Please note the changes that I have made. In the future, try to put the entirety of each mathematical expression into one `$...$`. For instance, `$A + B  \geq C$` is better than `A + B $\geq$ C`.

Comment: Regarding the proof you added, your first line $X_1^\perp\cap X_2^\perp=\{y:\langle y,x\rangle=0\ \ \forall x_1\in X_1,\ \ \forall x_2\in X_2\}$ doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to the first part.

We want to show that if $y \in X_2^\perp$, then $y \in X_1^\perp$. Consider any $y \in X_2^\perp$. By definition, this means that we have $\langle y,x \rangle = 0$ for every $x \in X_2$.

Now, consider any $x \in X_1$. It is also true that $x \in X_2$. So from what we just said, it follows that $\langle y, x \rangle = 0$.

Because $\langle y,x \rangle = 0$ for every $x \in X_1$, $y$ is an element of $X_1^\perp$, which is what we wanted.

Answering the second part requires that you similarly "unpack" the definition of the orthogonal complement.

---

In response to your comments: here is a way to write out the definition of all relevant sets:
$$
\begin{align}
X_1 + X_2 &= \{x: x = x_1 + x_2 \text{ with } x_1 \in X_1,x_2 \in X_2\}
\\ & = \{x_1 + x_2 : x_1 \in X_1, x_2 \in X_2\}\\
(X_1 + X_2)^\perp &= \{y: \langle y,x \rangle = 0 \text{ for all } x \in X_1 + X_2\}\\
&= \{y: \langle y,x_1 + x_2 \rangle = 0 \text{ for all } x_1 \in X_1, x_2 \in X_2\}\\
X_1^\perp + X_2^\perp &= \{y_1 + y_2 : y_1 \in X_1^\perp \text{ and }y_2 \in X_2^\perp\}\\
X_1 \cap X_2 &= \{x: x \in X_1 \text{ and }x \in X_2\}\\
X_1^\perp \cap X_2^\perp &= \{y: y \in X_1^\perp \text{ and } y \in X_2^\perp\}
\\ &= 
\{y : \langle y,x \rangle = 0 \text{ for all } x \text{ such that } x \in X_1 \text{ and all } x \text{ such that } x \in X_2\}\\
(X_1 \cap X_2)^\perp &= \{y : \langle y,x \rangle = 0 \text{ for all } x \in X_1 \cap X_2\}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks, that really hellped a lot. If my understanding is correct, then, regarding the second part it'd be  $(X_1 + X_2)^\perp = \{y \in V: \langle x_1,y\rangle=0 \ \ for \ \ all \ \ x_1\in X_1 \ \ and \ \ for \ \ all \ \ x_2\in X_2 \}$

Is this right? I also don't quite get how $X_1^\perp+X_2^\perp$ as well as $(X_1\cap X_2)^\perp$ and $X_1^\perp \cap X_2^\perp$ would be.

Comment: @DesperateSoul That's not the literal definition, but your statement is technicially correct. Do you understand what the subspace $X_1 + X_2$ is?

Comment: @DesperateSoul In response to that last statement, I have edited my answer to include the definitions of some of the sets that we need to think about. If you are still confused, I recommend that you try thinking of examples. For instance, what if $X_1$ is the $xy$-plane and $X_2$ is the $xz$-plane with $V = \Bbb R^3$?

Comment: Using the definitions you've included:

$X_1^\perp\cap X_2^\perp=\{y:\langle y,x\rangle=0\ \ \forall x_1\in X_1,\ \ \forall x_2\in X_2\}\Rightarrow\{y\in V:\langle x_1,y\rangle=0\ \ \& \ \ \langle x_2,y\rangle=0\ \ \forall x_1\in X_1,\ \ \forall x_2\in X_2\}\Rightarrow\{y\in V:\langle x_1,y\rangle + \langle x_2,y\rangle=0 \ \ \forall x_1\in X_1, \ \ \forall x_2\in X_2 \}=(X_1+X_2)^\perp$


Is this correct? As for (b), it is $X_1^\perp+X_2^\perp$ that we gotta work with I think, but I'm cluelesss as to how I'm supposed to approach it, it's very different from the others

Comment: @DesperateSoul I can't read your math properly, since you put it all into one line of a comment. Could you instead add this to your post after your question?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with LaTeX and formatting in general. I've updated the main post as you suggested.